# Bootstrap Style Guide for class ordering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've found several Style Guides about declaration ordering, attribute ordering but nothing about class ordering.

For example one developer does this:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-2 ml-3">My button</div>
```

Another developer does this:

```
<div class="mt-2 ml-3 btn btn-lg btn-primary">My button</div>
```

I would like to consistency for class ordering. Is there a special Style Guide I'm not aware of or are there any best practices for this?

Comment: This seems more like a set of standards for your group of developers to agree on. Either order is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any guide to class ordering because the order of classes on an element doesn't have any impact on specificity. They are simply references to the source CSS and will adhere to whatever cascading effects take place in the CSS.

We can a block of HTML with two conflicting classes, one that shows an element and one that hides the element.

```
<div class="show hide">
  <p>Some content</p>
</div>

.show { display: block; }
.hide { display: none; }
```

Here is the same element with inverse class orders.

```
<div class="hide show">
  <p>Some content</p>
</div>

.show { display: block; }
.hide { display: none; }
```

Both of these blocks will be hidden because they will adhere to the cascading effects of CSS.

I would recommend doing what makes the most sense to you and be consistent about it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you placing your button.
First, you have add these classes -

btn btn-lg btn-primary

because it acquires space in the particular div-
Then you have to add classes which affects button properties -

mt-2 ml-3